# "Runs in the family" alternate

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

"Engineering runs in my family" as my mother, father and brother are all engineers. But this phrase "runs in the family" seems too bold and flashy to start my resume. Please suggest an alternate that I can use.

Comment: Maybe "I come from a family of engineers" or "Engineering is in my DNA" or "I have lived and breathed engineering since I was an infant/child."

Comment: Engineering is a tradition in my family?

Comment: If you don't like any of the suggestions, could you at least explain why? Your question risks being closed for either lack of research, being too broad or opinion-based. A little research on your behalf would go a long way, and maybe this question will gain greater attention.

Comment: You're a *chip off the old block*. (Re. the title only. It doesn't really belong in a resume)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many other ways to rephrase the OP's “runs in the family” phrase. For instance, a little hyperbole gets the idea across

1. In my household we live and breathe engineering.
2. I have lived and breathed engineering ever since I could draw/hold a pencil/joystick in my hand.

> **[live and breathe something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/live-and-breathe-something)**
>   to be very enthusiastic about a particular activity and spend all the time you can doing it or talking about it

If the OP wishes to focus more on the familial tradition, they could use one of two phrases:

3. I was born into engineering
4. I am from the second generation of engineers.

> Vanessa Redgrave was **born into acting**, her arrival announced on a London stage by no less than Laurence Olivier. The **dynasty continued into another generation** with Redgrave's daughters Natasha and Joely Richardson. ([source](http://www.news.com.au/news/the-right-royal-redgrave-dynasty/news-story/01f68161463985aa90e3f229028de492))

or more simply

5. I come from a family of engineers

Comment: non-flashy resume : "Bla bla bla. Second generation engineer. Yadda yadda."